# Update and access alert message variable between Vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using VueJS with Laravel 6.0. What I'm trying to achieve is that to create global variables `alertStatus` and `alertMsg`, so that every time when an AJAX call is made, the global variables can be updated to display an alert message to user.

So I decided to use prototype variable for this case. The idea is that when AJAX call is success/fail in `User.vue`, the prototype variable should be updated, and `Alerts.vue` should display it accordingly.

However, it seems that the prototype variable display does not update when the data is changed in `User.vue` component.

I'm not sure if my methods are correct, would like to get some ideas from stackoverflow.

Thanks

**main.js**

```js
Vue.prototype.$alertStatus = '';
Vue.prototype.$alertMsg = [];
```

**Alerts.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="alert alert-light alert-elevate" role="alert">
        <div class="alert-icon">
           <i class="flaticon-warning kt-font-brand"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="alert-text">
            {{alertMsg}}
        </div>
    </div>               
</template>
```

**User.vue**

```html
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            var datatable = this.init();
            datatable.on('kt-datatable--on-ajax-fail', function(event, data){
                this.$alertStatus = data.responseJSON.status;
                this.$alertMsg = data.responseJSON.msg;
            });
        },
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tried `this.$set(this, '$alertMsg', data.responseJSON.msg)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using an event handler instead of the global prototype.

**Event.js** — credit to Jeffrey Way of https://laracasts.com/

```js
class Event {
    constructor() {
        this.vue = new Vue();
    }

    fire(event, data = null) {
        this.vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen(event, callback) {
        this.vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
}

export default Event;
```

I have outlined the basic usage below, plus I added a `v-if` to your alert to hide it when not in use.

**app.js**

```
import Event from './Event';
window.Event = new Event;
```

**Alerts.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="show" class="alert alert-light alert-elevate" role="alert">
        <div class="alert-icon"><i class="flaticon-warning kt-font-brand"></i></div>
        <div class="alert-text">
            {{ alert.msg }}
        </div>
    </div>               
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                alert: {},
                show: false,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            // listen for a global event 
            Event.listen('show-alert',alert => {
                this.alert = alert;
                this.show = true;
            });
        },
     }
</script>
```

**User.vue**

```html
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            var datatable = this.init();
            datatable.on('kt-datatable--on-ajax-fail', function(event, data){     
                // fire a global event          
                Event.fire('show-alert',{ 
                    status: data.responseJSON.status,
                    msg: data.responseJSON.msg,
                });
            });
        },
     }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. it worked perfectly. is it possible to link the laracast tutorial that you mentioned in your answer? thanks!

Comment: Sure! [Learn Vue 2: Step By Step](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step) | Or go directly to [Episode 13](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/13)  I can't find the repository on GitHub anymore, but if you want copies of the `Form.js` and `Errors.js` wrappers too, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with TableTanstack in VueJS - in order to get a clickable alert and a hover display for a given column I created a component to have a method for the alert and something to define props so I could inject the info into the component.  The end results:

The column definition where I want to have an edited date appear and hover over and clickable info showing much more:

```
   { accessorKey: 'Meta', 
     header: 'Edited',
     cell: ({ row }) => h(MetaButton, {
      displaydata: format(new Date(row.original.ModifiedOn), 'MMM d, yyyy'), 
      metadata: 
       ' Created:' + format(new Date(row.original.CreatedOn), 'MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss') + 
       ' By:' + row.original.CreatedBy +
       '\n Edited:' + format(new Date(row.original.ModifiedOn), 'MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss') + 
       ' By:' + row.original.ModifiedBy +
       '\nIn your timezone (UTC' + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*-1/60 +' )'
      }), 
      enableSorting:false },
```

The Component:

```
    <script setup>
    const showit = (msgg) => {
      console.log(msgg);
      alert(msgg);
    }
    
    const props = defineProps({
      displaydata: String,
      metadata: String,
    });
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <span :title="`${metadata}`" 
      class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500" 
      v-on:click=showit(metadata);
      >
      {{ displaydata }}&nbsp;&#9432;
      </span>
    </template>
```

The alert looks like this:
[Alert On Click - gets the info to the user][1]
[1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z50J.png)

The hover looks like this:
[When user hovers over the cell][2]
[2]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOfpy.png)

Thanks to drehimself github example repo (https://github.com/drehimself/tanstack-table-vue-example) - I forked it and made it into an example for a list of sheet music with the above mods - full code here: (https://github.com/gitberry/vue-tanstack-example)